# How should I go about writing a function for outputting tab delimited files?

Tags: php, io

Hey guys my problem is that I am having trouble comprehending how to write an array to a tab delimited file. The example I was given is like this: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=cRCkGexm
This is the same kind of tab structure that is used in Excel, so importing the file above into Excel should create a table that is readable.

My array looks like this http://pastebin.com/ChZhiC3m where each new indent is the index for the following indentations of the array. Example:

`array('Community' => array('Charities' => array(), 'Ecology' => array('Animal Rights' => array(), 'Biodiversity' => array(), 'Biome' => array(), 'Biosphere' => array(), 'Community Ecology' => array(), 'Ecosystem Ecology' => array(), 'Forests' => array()/* and they keep on going..*/)))`

So my question is, what sort of nested loop should I use? Should the function be recursive? The difficult part I see is how there are multiple categories per column which makes it kind of a mess.

If you know of any libraries or helper classes that have already been created, I would appreciate them greatly! Thanks!

Note: the array will never be deeper than three categories

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($data as $cat=>$rest)
foreach($rest as $subcat=>$places)
foreach($places as $place)
echo "$cat $subcat $place";
```

Comment: this answer is not relevant to problem.

Comment: then you must have a different problem